# Python, Looping through subdirectories for zip files, OS Error Invalid Argument \\

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to look into my directory for zip files and perform a function on them. It does seem to loop through some of the files correctly but gets stuck with  `OS Error \\`

Directory structure is like:

```
 //Stack/Over/Flow/2022 - 10/Original.zip 
 //Stack/Over/Flow/2022 - 09/Next file.zip
```

function i call:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import pandas as pd


def process_files(files: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    file_mapping = {}
    for file in files:
        #data_mapping = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(ZipFile(file).read(Path(file).stem)), sheet_name=None)
        
        archive = ZipFile(file)

        # find file names in the archive which end in `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.xlsb`, ...
        files_in_archive = archive.namelist()
        excel_files_in_archive = [
            f for f in files_in_archive if Path(f).suffix[:4] == ".xls"
        ]
        # ensure we only have one file (otherwise, loop or choose one somehow)
        assert len(excel_files_in_archive) == 1

        # read in data
        data_mapping = pd.read_excel(
            BytesIO(archive.read(excel_files_in_archive[0])),
            sheet_name=None,
        )

        row_counts = []
        for sheet in list(data_mapping.keys()):
            row_counts.append(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))

        file_mapping.update({file: sum(row_counts)})

    frame = pd.DataFrame([file_mapping]).transpose().reset_index()
    frame.columns = ["file_name", "row_counts"]

    return frame
```

code:

```
dir_path = r'\\stack\over\flow'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        print(files)
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            df = process_files(os.path.join(root, file))
            print(df) #function
        else:
            print("nyeh")
```

Error:

```
runfile('/test.py', wdir='test python location')
['History Detail view (page 5) - Nov 2021.zip', 'Original - All fields - 11012021 - 11302021.zip', 'Other fields - 11012021 - 11302021.zip', 'Qualified - All fields - 11012021 - 11302021.zip', 'WPS Report (page 3) 11012021 - 11302021.zip']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 75, in <module>
    df = process_files(os.path.join(root, file))

  File "test.py", line 21, in process_files
    archive = ZipFile(file)

  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\diamond\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\'
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I bypass this?

Comment: `dir_path = r'\\stack\over\flow'` Why does this begin with two backslashes?

Comment: It is a nas shared drive in reality. So shows that in the windows explorer

Comment: What does `print(os.path.join(root, file))` show? It seems like either that or `ZipFile()` doesn't like paths that begin with two backslashes.

Comment: so when i do this `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file))`  it prints : `\\Stack\Over\Flow\2021 - 11\History Detail view (page 5) - Nov 2021.zip` then i get an error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\'`